# Download pictures to specific folder Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a problem with this line of code I'm writing.
Basically it takes the url of the picture or video from several Instagram posts and it downloads them one by one with the name 'name0.png','name1.png','name2.png' etc and then it shows all the names.

My only issue is it only downloads them to the folder where my code is located at, but i want to send them to a specific path.

The code is as follows:

```
def save_images(name,posts):

    print("Downloading Images....")

    pngnames = []

    i = 1

    #Load each post
    for post in posts:
        pngname = str(name)+str(i)+'.png'
        driver.get(post)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#react-root > section > main > div > div.ltEKP > article > div > div.qF0y9.Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_._4EzTm > div > div > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span._15y0l > button > div.QBdPU.B58H7 > svg > path')))

        image = '#react-root > section > main > div > div > article > div > div._97aPb.wKWK0 > div > div > div.KL4Bh > img'
        images = '#react-root > section > main > div > div.ltEKP > article > div > div._97aPb.wKWK0 > div > div.pR7Pc > div.qF0y9.Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_._4EzTm.O1flK.D8xaz.fm1AK.TxciK.yiMZG > div > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.KL4Bh > img'
        video = '#react-root > section > main > div > div.ltEKP > article > div > div._97aPb.wKWK0 > div > div > div > div > div > video'
        #Get source URL of post
        if driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,image):
            downloadUrl = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,image)
        elif driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,video):
            downloadUrl = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, video)
        elif driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,images):
            downloadUrl = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,images)
        else:
            print("Couldnt get post url.")
            continue


        with open(pngname, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(downloadUrl.screenshot_as_png)

        i=i+1
        pngnames.append(pngname)


    return pngnames
```

What should I add for it to send these downloaded files to a specific folder?

'

Comment: You can define `pngname` however you want, including a path to any folder.

Comment: Can you write me the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `pngname` however you want, including a path to any folder. `os.path` is your friend when generating and manipulating path names. Note that the directory needs to exist, otherwise an error will be raised.

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/myself/Documents"
pngname = "myfile"

with open(os.path.join(path, pngname), 'wb') as f:
    ...
```